# Как роутить url основанный на регулярных выражениях c++?

Tags: c++, регулярные-выражения, url, роутинг

У меня есть регулярки и ассоциированные с ними обработчики, какие более быстрые способы находить регулярку, к которой подходит пришедший url чем просто последовательный перебор всех имеющихся регулярок?
Для регулярных выражений используется бустовый движок.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возникала подобная проблема. И самое лучшее, что нашел - это объединить выражения в группы и дальше простым if сразу выбирать группу. Также тяжелые регулярки обрамляются "простыми условиями".

То есть, если регулярка должна начинаться на "/doc", дальше за ней идет длинный хвост регулярки и больше нет урлов, которые начинаются на "/doc", то просто пишем

```
if (url[0] == '/' && url[1] == 'd') {
  //а тут уже полноценная регулярка
}
```

substr лучше не использовать - лишнее выделение памяти не к чему.

У меня такой подход дал где то двукратное ускорение в обработке "роутинга".

Но у этого способа есть большой недостаток - если сама регулярка поменялась, то нужно и условия обновить.

Второй способ - делать дерево с урлов и будет не линейное время, а за логарифм. Но он будет достаточно эффективен, если урлов хотя бы десяток-другой. Этот способ похож на предыдущий, но тут система многоуровневая и при правильном подходе возможно и не нужны будут регулярки.

Comment: А как объединять их в группы? Можно пример?

Comment: я не знаю Ваши урлы, поэтому мой пример может быть сильно-сильно притянут за уши. Но в целом, если у Вас есть урлы, которые смотрят в /app, /doc, /help, то можно сделать вначале быструю проверку на начала, а сами урлы туда забросить в соответствующую группу. А также отсортировать их по частотности.